# Java ThreadPoolExecutor for timed tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I'd like to know if there exists a class that runs tasks for a timed duration, if that duration exceeds then it errors out or gives a return status of fail. If there isn't, how simple would this be to implement in Java using ThreadPoolExecutor class.

After some looking around, there are some examples working with ThreadPoolExecutor class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.orTimeout(duration)` uses a JVM-wide scheduled executor service to cancel the future. This doesn't halt or interrupt the running task, though, which has to be done in your own application logic. Basically the approach one uses is a scheduled timer (aka watchdog) to cancel a running task by setting a flag, with that task checking periodically for an early exit.